# How to make an R script always listening?

Tags: mysql, r, cron

First of all excuse me if this is a basic question or the wording is wrong, I am no expert.

What I need to do is create an `R script` which has to be *always* retrieving and analyzing data which is continuously stored into a `MySQL` database.

My first thought to solve it was to simply to run a cron job every 1 minute, but that proves to be too slow for my needs. Ideally I would need it to be alway there waiting for new values to arrive and apply the logic of the script.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated so I can learn more about it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output like? An infinite loop comes to mind: `while(TRUE) {do_something()}`.

Comment: The first thing to pops into my mind is a `for()` loop whose first line is a `sys.sleep()` statement.

Comment: Thanks, the output is an execution of an api call. I will try the `while` and the `for`. The thing is that there is no real end to the script,so there won't be a `FALSE` condition. Maybe I can play with the `time`, but you put me some ideas in my mind. Thanks

Comment: @JordanBelf: I assume, you are going to use the data output it in some application. If I'm right, why can't that application trigger the `R Script`? You could look for packages like `Rcpp, rJava, OPENCPU, etc.,` where you get the flexibility of embedding R with your application and let your scheduler schedules the job. So that you can keep track of any surprise failures in `R` and the `R Script` as well.....